# MySQL database import generates unusable database dumps

Tags: mysql

I'm taking backup of my database and it has text field which contains following content:

Original data:
"Rock'n Roll"

Database backup:
"Rock\'n Roll"

What it should be in backup:
"Rock''n Roll"

So what could be causing this error in my MySQL configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unusable? `Rock\'n Roll` should be a perfectly valid form. Backslash is just an escape character telling MySQL that the following `'` should be considered as data and not as SQL delimiter `'`.

Did you try actually restoring you backup?

Comment: yes and it fails

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: It returns "Unknown object in backup file" error in target linux system. Itake backup from Windows 7 32bit system.

Comment: I tried to restore database in my Windows 7 and it worked, but exact same file gives that error in Linux. I use MySQL Admin over SSH to restore database in Linux.

Comment: Problem was in MySQL admin, when I used mysql from command line in linux it worked.